# How do I handle partially initialized classes

Tags: python, class, oop

My question concerns a class that I am writing that may or may not be fully initialized.  The basic goal is to take a `match_id` and open the corresponding `match_url` (example: http://dota2lounge.com/match?m=1899) and then grab some properties out of the webpage.  The problem is some `match_ids` will result in 404 pages (http://dota2lounge.com/404).

When this happens, there won't be a way to determine the winner of the match, so the rest of the `Match` can't be initialized.  I have seen this causing problems with methods of the `Match`, so I added the lines to initialize everything to `None` if `self._valid_url` is `False`.  This works in principal, but then I'm adding a line each time a new attribute is added, and it seems prone to errors down the pipeline (in methods, etc.)  It also doesn't alert the user that this class wasn't properly initialized.  They would need to call `.is_valid_match()` to determine that.

tl;dr: **What is the best way to handle classes that may be only partially initiated?**  Since this is a hobby project and I'm looking to learn, I'm open to pretty much any solutions (trying new things), including other classes or whatever.  Thanks.

This is an abbreviated version of the code containing the relevant portions (Python 3.3):

```python
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Match(object):
    def __init__(self, match_id):
        self.match_id = match_id
        self.match_url = self.__determine_match_url__()
        self._soup = self.__get_match_soup__()
        self._valid_match_url = self.__determine_match_404__()
        if self._valid_match_url:
            self.teams, self.winner = self.__get_teams_and_winner__()

        # These lines were added, but I'm not sure if this is correct.
        else:
            self.teams, self.winner = None, None

    def __determine_match_url__(self):
        return 'http://dota2lounge.com/match?m=' + str(self.match_id)

    def __get_match_soup__(self):
        return BeautifulSoup(urlopen(self.match_url))

    def __get_match_details__(self):
        return self._soup.find('section', {'class': 'box'})

    def __determine_match_404__(self):
        try:
            if self._soup.find('h1').text == '404':
                return False
        except AttributeError:
            return True

    def __get_teams_and_winner__(self):
        teams = [team.getText() for team in
                 self._soup.find('section', {'class': 'box'}).findAll('b')]
        winner = False
        for number, team in enumerate(teams):
            if ' (win)' in team:
                teams[number] = teams[number].replace(' (win)', '')
                winner = teams[number]

        return teams, winner

    def is_valid_match(self):
        return all([self._valid_match_url, self.winner])
```

Comment: Just a comment about this:  You are doing a lot of work within your constructor (e.g. downloading a webpage).  There is debate about the advisability of this.  E.g. it can make it harder to test your class.

Comment: Totally OT but I suggest you have a look at python-requests - there are many other ways your request could fail, and searching the response body for a "<h1>404</h1>" tag is not the most reliable way to find out what you got - HTTP response codes are way more reliable.

Comment: Also: `__magic__` names (two leadings underscore, two trailing underscores) are reserved for the language.

Comment: To clarify Bruno's comment, it is fine to name your method `__foo` but not `__foo__`. Typically only a single underscore is used to denote the method/function is private.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers that is only by convention... double leading underscore leads to name mangling however so it is very hard to access methods/ variables with double leading underscores externally from the class(which is sometimes the intention, this is the closest python has to truly private variables(and methods), however if you know the name mangling rules it is still externally accessible)

Comment: @SeanPerry afaik its fine to name it either way (at least in 2.6)

Comment: Thanks for all the great comments so far. @jeffrey_t_b, could this be something where the webpage, etc. is downloaded and passed to the `__init__` instead?  As for the `__magic__` names, my intention was to separate things that should be public-facing from things internal to the class.  Since it's only me using it, it's not too big of a concern, but good practice to learn these things.  So from a language perspective the only thing that results in mangling is double leading underscore, and the rest is by convention?

Comment: @JoranBeasley, it is a violation of PEP8 and would confuse anyone who has coded in Python for any reasonable length of time. Remember, we write code for two audiences -- the computer and people. Just because the computer understands it does not mean the people will.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Like a lot of things in Python, it's indeed convention - but it's still important. Also FYI there's no name mangling on `__magic__` names, and name mangling is not meant to make anything "private" but to protect attributes / methods from being _accidentaly_ overridden in child classes.

Comment: @Garth5689 : in Python the idiomatic way to mark an attribute as "internal" (ie : implementation detail, not part of the public API) is to add one single leading underscore. Every Python programmer will know what it means.

Comment: Python does not mangle names like C++ does. The double underscore names are 'magic' and are invoked when the needs arise. So `__init__` means constructor, `__add__` means override addition symbol, `__call__` means allow to be called like a function, etc. Since there is no private support there is the idiom of a single underscore means private. In some places the language will honor this like when you define a function `def _foo` in a module and then elsewhere do 'from module import *'. The `_foo` function will not be imported.

Comment: yeah thats right ... I misspoke about the mangling (actually I didnt know until I tested it) ... as for confusing people I dont think its very confusing when I see it (although in general I avoid leading/trailing underscores in my own code ...)

Comment: BTW, since you mention this is 3.3 code. `return 'http://dota2lounge.com/match?m=' + str(self.match_id)` is better written `return 'http://dota2lounge.com/match?m={}'.format(self.match_id)`

Comment: python does name-mangle `__var = whatever` and `def __fn(self,...)` but double underscores on both sides do not get mangled ...

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, I'm going to research this stuff some more and possibly refactor to take some of the heavy lifting out of this class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would raise an exception, handle that in your creation code (wherever you call `some_match = Match(match_id)`), and probably don't add it to whatever list you may or may not be using...

For a better answer, you might want to include in your question the code that instantiates all your `Match` objects.

Comment: Right now, it's just going into a list of matches, something like: `[Match(id) for id in range(200,211)]` or something similar.  I haven't written much code to do the actual analysis or fun stuff yet.  But basically, I could add these to a list with a `try` `except` block to get only the valid matches, correct?

Comment: Instead of writing a "me too" kind of answer I will chime in here. Consider passing the url as a parameter that defaults to None. To be explicit where @mhlester is being more implicit your constructor is doing too much work. For this case it may be OK but it is a bad habit to get into. Consider what happens when you make a list of Match objects, one for each logged in User? Wouldn't you rather have check code around 'for each item in list, is it OK else handle it' instead of around `[ match(foo) for foo in user_list ]`?